# How to get current repository in VSTS Code Hub

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am researching on extending visual studio services by adding a code hub. With the help of the online samples and documentation, I am able to add a hub under code hub group. But now the issue is that i am not able find any way in my hub page to know the currently selected repository. Please guide me on this. I am specifically targeting git repositories in my hub.

**Edited:**
Screenshot Showing the project dropdown , repository dropdown and new custom Code Hub named "Git Graph"
[image]
What I need is an option to know which repository is selected while the user is in the custom code hub. the method getWebContext() only lists the information till the project level. Where as it should give me the current repository too.

Comment: do you want to retrieve selected repository from a package?

Comment: When under code hub for a particular project, there is a dropdown menu, where we can select the repository. Now I want to know which repository the user has selected when I am in the custom hub I am creating.

Comment: @ColeWu-MSFT are you able to find any solution for this?

Comment: Based on my test, the git repository can't be switch for custom Code Hub. If I switch Repository, it redirect to File page, then I click custom code hub, the repository switch to the default repository (same as team project name) automatically. What's your result?

Comment: I don't want to switch the repository. I want to know, which repository is currently selected via code hub repository dropdown, so that in the custom code hub page I can reference the same information. When I execute the get web context, I get the information till the project, but not the current repository. I am forced to provide a custom repository selection dropdown in the page. This defeats the purpose as the user may have selected the different repo in code hub than that of one he has selected in custom code hub page.

Comment: The selected repository is the same as project name if you can't switch repository when in custom code hub page. So what do you mean current repository?

Comment: @starain-MSFT  I will post the screenshots making it more clear. Give me some time.

Comment: hi @starain-MSFT, I have update the screenshot

Comment: Can you share the extension on the OneDrive? The extension is loaded in a Iframe from the cross domain, I am afraid that you can't get selected repository.

Comment: @starain-MSFT it is not complete yet and in very early stages. I know that the extensions are loaded in iframe. I was just looking for the APIs to get the currently selected repository. I feel that the purpose of have a code hub tab is defeated if the extensions are not able to see the full context. I guess MS should extend the API to provide that required information, if tgey are not already providing the same.

Comment: Can you share the project on the OneDrive? I can't switch the repository in my extension. I will try to find a way to get current repository.

Comment: @starain-MSFT I will post the same and share to you. I have not observed the behavior you are telling. But let me see if it is happening same for me too.